# Torah commentaries in modern Hebrew

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, hebrew, pentateuch-chumash

I’m not sure if such thing exists, but I wonder if there are books which contain classical (if it has modern ones, also fine, but not necessarily) Torah commentaries in Modern Hebrew? What I mean is: It rephrases or directly converted most common commentaries such as from Rashi, Ramban, etc. from middle century Hebrew into modern one, so a person knowing only Hebrew which spoken nowadays, will be able to read and completely understands all most common commentaries of Torah.

Comment: Such a translation is essentially a commentary on a commentary because the exact meaning of certain words and ideas within various commentaries may be debated. And so there are commentators who strive to explain earlier commentators - these are called "supercommentators" with "supercommentaries". One modern one that comes to mind is רש"י כפשוטו on Rashi.

Comment: Only thing I know like that is Koren Talmud, but I don't think it does much commentary, just the gemara into MH

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will probably be לשם's רש"י כפשוטו, which is essentially a collection of various peirushim on Rashi but written into the text of Rashi. Meaning, they will expand Rashi by adding in words in between his words in such a way that they explain this peirush's explenation of Rashi seemlessly. They do this in modern hebrew even though the original commentary to Rashi was written hundreds of years ago. In fact, I personally understand "yeshivish" or older hebrew much better, and I often understand the explenation of Rashi better by looking up the original commentary, so if you understand modern hebrew better, I can imagine this being the reverse for you. You should be able to find it very easily online or in stores. Another option may be עוז והדר's רמב"ן המבואר, which does something kinda maybe similar. This option is much more expensive (and twice as many volumes). Another more recent work on chumash could be R' S.R. Hirsch's commentary which was translated from its original German into modern Hebrew.

Another option perhaps to look into is אוצר מפרשי התורה by Mechon Yerushalayim. While it's not a rewritten translation of the rishonim on chumash, it is a phenominal likut of them written up in modern hebrew. Maybe it's worth giving it a try.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://ozvehadar.us/chumash-mikraos-gedolos-hamevuar/) set from Oz Vehadar matches what you are looking for. They also have sets with individual mefarshim. I believe it is in the style of their famous Mesivta edition of Gemara.

Comment: I don't think it's in the same style as their mesivta set. Mesivta is more comparable to Rashi k'pshuto which inserts words into the main text to include whatever peirush they're using. This set is more like footnotes with explanations if I'm not mistaken.